# Want to make Font Awesome icons clickable

Tags: html, font-awesome

So I am new to web development and I am trying to link font awesome icons to my social profiles but am unsure of how to do that. I tried using an a href tag but it made all of the icons take me to one site instead of the one I wanted. Here is the code:

```
 <i class="fa fa-dribbble fa-4x"></i>
 <i class="fa fa-behance-square fa-4x"></i>
 <i class="fa fa-linkedin-square fa-4x"></i>
 <i class="fa fa-twitter-square fa-4x"></i>
 <i class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-4x"></i>
```

I'd like for each of these icons to go to their respective profiles. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 102):

You can wrap those elements in anchor tag

like this

```
<a href="your link here"> <i class="fa fa-dribbble fa-4x"></i></a>
<a href="your link here"> <i class="fa fa-behance-square fa-4x"></i></a>
<a href="your link here"> <i class="fa fa-linkedin-square fa-4x"></i></a>
<a href="your link here"> <i class="fa fa-twitter-square fa-4x"></i></a>
<a href="your link here"> <i class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-4x"></i></a>
```

*Note: Replace `href="your link here"` with your desired link e.g. `href="https://www.stackoverflow.com"`.*

Answer (score 42):

If you don't want it to add it to a link, you can just enclose it within a span and that would work.

`<span id='clickableAwesomeFont'><i class="fa fa-behance-square fa-4x"></span>`

in your css, then you can:

```
#clickableAwesomeFont {
     cursor: pointer
}
```

Then in java script, you can just add a click handler.

In cases where it's actually **not** a link, I think this is much cleaner and using a link would be changing its semantics and abusing its meaning.

Comment: Do you have any example of this? It's not working with my case.

Answer (score 9):

Using bootstrap with font awesome.

```
<a class="btn btn-large btn-primary logout" href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-sign-out" aria-hidden="true">Logout</i>
</a>
```

Answer (score 7):

I found this worked best for my usecase:

```
<i class="btn btn-light fa fa-dribbble fa-4x" href="#"></i>
<i class="btn btn-light fa fa-behance-square fa-4x" href="#"></i>
<i class="btn btn-light fa fa-linkedin-square fa-4x" href="#"></i>
<i class="btn btn-light fa fa-twitter-square fa-4x" href="#"></i>
<i class="btn btn-light fa fa-facebook-square fa-4x" href="#"></i>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Please use Like below.
<a style="cursor: pointer" **(click)="yourFunctionComponent()"** >
<i class="fa fa-dribbble fa-4x"></i>
 </a>
```

> The above can be used so that the fa icon will be shown and also on
> the click function you could write your logic.

Answer (score -1):

In your css add a class:

```
.fa-clickable {
    cursor:pointer;
    outline:none;
}
```

Then add the class to the clickable fontawesome icons (also an id so you can differentiate the clicks):

```
 <i class="fa fa-dribbble fa-4x fa-clickable" id="epd-dribble"></i>
 <i class="fa fa-behance-square fa-4x fa-clickable" id="epd-behance"></i>
 <i class="fa fa-linkedin-square fa-4x fa-clickable" id="epd-linkedin"></i>
 <i class="fa fa-twitter-square fa-4x fa-clickable" id="epd-twitter"></i>
 <i class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-4x fa-clickable" id="epd-facebook"></i>
```

Then add a handler in your jQuery

```
$(document).on("click", "i", function(){
    switch (this.id) {
        case "epd-dribble":
            // do stuff
            break;
        // add additional cases
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
             <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook-square"></i></a> 
             <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-twitter-square"></i></a> 
             <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-basketball-ball"></i></a> 
             <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-google-plus-square"></i></a>


              All you have to do is wrap your font-awesome icon link in your HTML 
                               with an anchor tag.
        Following this format:
                   <a href="Link here"> <font-awesome icon code> </a>
```

Comment: What does this add to the answer that was given in 2014?

Answer (score -2):

Simply add font awesome icons into the anchor tag and then change the anchor color in CSS.
Here is an example:

**HTML CODE**

```
<a class="icons-default" href="" target="_blank"><i class="social-icons social-icon fab fa-linkedin fa-4x"
                    id="social-icons-linkedin"></i></a>

            <a class="icons-default" href="" target="_blank"><i class="social-icons social-icon fab fa-facebook fa-4x"
                    id="social-icons-facebook"></i></a>

            <a class="icons-default" href="" target="_blank"><i class="social-icons social-icon fab fa-twitter fa-4x"
                    id="social-icons-twitter"></i></a>
                    
            <a class="icons-default" href="" target="_blank"><i class="social-icons social-icon fas fa-envelope fa-4x"
                    id="social-icons-mail"></i></a>
```

**CSS**

Let's change the default color to black.

```
.icons-default{color: black;}
```

Comment: Your answer does not contain any new approach. Nesting the icon in a link element has already been suggested.

Comment: Duplicate answer, unneeded

Comment: @Jonathon this is not the duplicate answer, it has solved the problem in my case, that's why I thought to help the community.