# Clickable font-awesome icons in a clickable dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, html, css, font-awesome

I'm using two Fontawesome icons without any text for a clickable dropdown menu, but these icons won't toggle the dropdown menu. When I click on a padding around them, dropdown works. As you can see in the W3schools example, clicks on the text and padding are working, but not on the icon. How could I fix that?

```js
/* When the user clicks on the button, 
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(e) {
  if (!e.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
    var myDropdown = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
    if (myDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
      myDropdown.classList.remove('show');
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn,
.dropbtn:focus {
  background-color: red;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="navbar">
    <a href="#home">Home</a>
    <a href="#news">News</a>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn" onclick="myFunction()">Dropdown
    <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
  </button>
      <div class="dropdown-content" id="myDropdown">
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `.fa` to your function

Code:

```
// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(e) {
  if (!e.target.matches('.dropbtn, .fa')) {
    var myDropdown = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
    if (myDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
      myDropdown.classList.remove('show');
    }
  }
}
```

Fiddle:

```js
/* When the user clicks on the button, 
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(e) {
  if (!e.target.matches('.dropbtn, .fa')) {
    var myDropdown = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
    if (myDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
      myDropdown.classList.remove('show');
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn,
.dropbtn:focus {
  background-color: red;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="navbar">
    <a href="#home">Home</a>
    <a href="#news">News</a>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn" onclick="myFunction()">Dropdown
    <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
  </button>
      <div class="dropdown-content" id="myDropdown">
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This works, but I'm having weird issues with .fas icons, some areas of the icons are clickable, some are not... I'm really confused. I'm using these two: .fas, .fa-globe-americas, .fa-chevron-down

Comment: Here's something that may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26814297/want-to-make-font-awesome-icons-clickable

Comment: It didn't help sadly. I just realised, when I click on empty parts of the icon, dropdown toggles, but when I click on the actual color/icon it doesn't.

Comment: Weird, is there a live version anywhere?

Comment: Try using a `span` tag? They can be sort of interchangeable even though FA recommends `i`

Comment: I don't have it live. I tried span as well, didn't work. I'll try to recreate it in some online code editor

Comment: Works perfectly here, I don't know what's causing the issue...
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PrWRKj

Answer (score 0):

May be like adding a new class for those elements we need to escape the close click:-

```js
/* When the user clicks on the button, 
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction() {    document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show"); 
}

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(e) {

  if (!e.target.matches('.esc')) {
  var myDropdown = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
    if (myDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
      myDropdown.classList.remove('show');
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 16px;  
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn, .dropbtn:focus {
  background-color: red;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="navbar">
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <div class="dropdown">

  <button class="dropbtn esc" onclick="myFunction()" >Dropdown
    <i class="fa fa-caret-down esc" ></i>
  </button>
  
  <div class="dropdown-content" id="myDropdown">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
  </div> 
</div>
</body>
</html>
```