# HTML icon links - button or <a> with CSS icon

Tags: html, css, symfony, hyperlink, icons

This is a newbie question I'm afraid but hey, we've all got to start somewhere and I'm going round in circles trying to google this.
How do I create a bar of icons that do certain functions, for example log in/out, print a report, go to homepage etc. Very much like the icons on the top right of this page that link to the inbox, achievements, help center, etc.
Do I use  link in the html and use CSS to style the icons?
Or do I use a button?
I'm using Symfony if that makes a difference.
Thank you in advance to any kind helpers.

Comment: And would links like these go in a navigation bar? Would this stack overflow page, for example, be likely to be putting the links inside <nav> </nav>

Comment: Buttons are for **actions**, links are for moving to another location...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30936608/why-are-buttons-discouraged-from-navigation

Comment: Do you mean with `icon` the `<i>` tag?

Answer (score 1):

Works same way but for links try to use "a" and for actions like submit or pop-up try to use "button".

Answer (score 1):

Just style the items you want and if you want to make them clickable (link), just surround them with an a-Tag.

Example with a clickable Fontawesome Icon:

```
<a href="your link here"> <i class="fa fa-dribbble"></i></a>
```

Reference:
[Want to make Font Awesome icons clickable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26814297/want-to-make-font-awesome-icons-clickable)

Comment: It should be the accepted answer because it shows an icon as child of a link.However an icon as child of a button does not work.